# como hacer un array_column en javascript

Tags: javascript, php, array

Mi idea es poder acceder a una  a los nombres y poder insertar o cambiar los valores de la persona que quiera. Por ejemplo como puedo editar la calle, puerta y piso?, esto se que se puede hacer en php con array_column pero no se cual seria la equivalencia en JavaScript.

```
    var persona = {
     persona1: {
         nombre: "juan",
         casa: {
             calle: "calle",
             numero: "1",
             piso: {
                 planta: "1",
                 puerta: "1"
             },
         },
         telefono:"612345789",
     },
     persona2: {
        nombre: "ana",
        casa: {
            calle: "calle2",
            numero: "2",
            piso: {
                planta: "2",
                puerta: "2"
            },
        },
        telefono:"612345789",
    }

 }
```

Se que podría hacer en php, pero en este caso lo necesito hacer con JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola @David Gonzalo eso al ser un JSON en javascript es un objeto solamente tienes que navegar por sus propiedades, mas o menos como lo arias en php o en cualquier otro lenguaje.

```js
 var persona = {
     persona1: {
         nombre: "juan",
         casa: {
             calle: "calle",
             numero: "1",
             piso: {
                 planta: "1",
                 puerta: "1"
             },
         },
         telefono:"612345789",
     },
     persona2: {
        nombre: "ana",
        casa: {
            calle: "calle2",
            numero: "2",
            piso: {
                planta: "2",
                puerta: "2"
            },
        },
        telefono:"612345789",
    }

 }
 
 //Asi modificamos
persona.persona1.casa.calle = "Calle barcelona";
persona.persona1.casa.numero = 5
persona.persona1.casa.piso.planta = 1
persona.persona1.casa.piso.puerta = 5

//Imprimimos
console.log('Calle: '+ persona.persona1.casa.calle);
console.log('numero: '+ persona.persona1.casa.numero);
console.log('planta: '+ persona.persona1.casa.piso.planta);
console.log('puerta: '+ persona.persona1.casa.piso.puerta);
```

Comment: podria definir la 'ruta' por ejemplo (persona.persona1.casa.calle) en una variable? o alguna forma de hacer que coja la 'ruta' automáticamente?

Comment: Hola @David Gonzalo si quieres poner **persona.persona1.casa.calle** en una variable solamente tienes que hacer lo siguiente. `var calle = persona.persona1.casa.calle; console.log(calle);`

Comment: Eres un grande, mercii